# how can i import a function in another function from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, import

i am trying to access "changenavitemstate" function from "Nvbarlink" file

Nvbarlink file:
[image]
the file that i want the function to be imported:
[image]

but it give me this error:
[image]

i try to use props to access that function but it did not work for me

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

you can define "changenavitemstate" before Nvbarlink with export statement like this.

```
   export const changenavitemstate = (argument1, argument2.....) => {
-----function here---------
}

// here will be your component
const Nvbarlink = () => {

}
```

You can always use changenavitemstate in Nvbarlink component and you can also import that function somewere like this in Dashboard.

```
import { changenavitemstate } from "filepath"
```

but **you are changing state valued** in that function so you **will not be able to do that outside of the component**.

To solve these issues you will have to use **context api or redux or alternatives**. So you can get and set value of variables from any components.